# Import multiple XML files in access

Tags: xml, ms-access

I have a lot of xml files, 365 to be exact. I need to import them all in access. All the xml are of similar structure except sometimes some fields might be more sometimes less. Is there a way to import so many files together and automatically update database structure as that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Access supports Scripting/Macros. Refer to the Access documentation/help to learn more about these and write a program that fits exactly your needs.